# How do I reference two active ngFor s at the same time?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Im using Angular 6.0. I have a list of properties (propertiesList) and a list of objects with those properties (objectList).I need to display all the objects in a table where each column is one of the properties.

I've read a bunch of SO posts about using ngFor inside ngFor to iterate over a list within a list, but that is not what I am trying to do. So before you link me to one of those please read my example code. I want to iterate over an object using a list. Problem is, that object is in a list

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th *ngFor="let property of addedColumns">{{property}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of objectList">
        <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let property of addedColumns">{{obj.properties.property}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TS Object Example

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class Example implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}

    //dynamic in real version
    addedColumns = ['prop1','prop2', 'prop3']

    //also dynamic
    objectList = [
        {name:'1',properties:{prop1:'ex',prop2:'ex',prop3:'ex'}},
        {name:'2',properties:{prop1:'ex2',prop2:'ex2',prop3:'ex2'}},
        {name:'3',properties:{prop1:'ex3',prop2:'ex3',prop3:'ex3'}}
    ]

}
```

Clearly the problem is with '{{obj.properties.property}}' in the HTML, but I can't figure out what the proper reference would be. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to reference a property name with variable, you should parenthesize with `[]`.

This would work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th *ngFor="let property of addedColumns">{{property}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of objectList">
        <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let property of addedColumns">{{obj.properties[property]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That results in a template parser error: 'Unexpected Token ['

Comment: I found my error, I forgot to remove the '.' between properties and [property]. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to further my education, I couldn't find the documentation where it says how to do this. Do you know where I would look for this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

There's two way to reference a property, `obj.prop` and `obj['prop']`. Replace `'prop'` to `propVar` in latter one, `propVar` in `obj[propVar]` is replaced with that value in run time.